# Сan i package Playwright in React Native desktop app?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, react-native, playwright

I'm using playwright to automate some actions in the browser. Is it possible to make a desktop application that launches the playwright on the click of a button?

tried to pack into one executable file, but playwright didn't pack

Comment: Playwright does not support native apps only web.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.